# Can work computer pick up iPhone browser history of connected to personal wifi

Tags: account-security

Can my work computer pick up my iPhone's browsing history when I am working from home and they are connected to my personal wifi?  My laptop is connected VPN at home.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If this was possible, your browsing history would be exposed to everyone connected to the same wifi your phone is using.

Comment: You need to provide the experts here a lot more info. As a total guess though... browser syncs and iPhone hand-off expose browsing "history". If you are browsing the web on the iPhone and syncing to your laptop, which is directing all traffic through the VPN you may be sending this info through their network.